# Git clone only a subdirectory, at the root of the current directory

Tags: git, directory, git-clone, sparse-matrix

I have a few folders on my Git repo:

```
folder1/suba
folder2/subb
folder3/subc
```

And locally I have the public folder on my web server.

```
http://domain.com/
```

points to that folder

```
~/apps/appname/public
```

I would like to effectively do a git clone of the `folder3/subc` to the `public` folder on the server. Now I know about the sparse checkout, but that retains the folder hierarchy (like so `~/apps/appname/public/folder3/subc`).

I do not want that hierarchy and would like to checkout the content of folder3/subc directly into the public folder.

Is that possible?

Comment: do a git clone locally and then move the folder to web server

Comment: I need to do regular git pull to update the code on the server, moving it will break the Git functionality.

Comment: Create a new directory and then copy the stuff to it

Answer (score 3):

If `~/apps/appname/public` is on a shared filesystem, and your webserver doesn't alter the checked-out files, you can maintain a dedicated index of its contents and just use `git read-tree -um` to update the filesystem from any commit you like:

```
( 
  export GIT_INDEX_FILE=/path/to/repo/.git/appname-public-manifest
  export GIT_WORK_TREE=~/apps/appname/public
  git read-tree -um `git write-tree` master:folder3/subc
)
```

The `git write-tree` writes a tree for `git read-tree` to inspect, and the read-tree applies the differences between what's there now and what's in the specified tree to the index and worktree.

If there's nothing in that directory already there's no need to initialize, otherwise

```
( 
  export GIT_INDEX_FILE=/path/to/repo/.git/appname-public-manifest
  export GIT_WORK_TREE=~/apps/appname/public
  git read-tree --empty   # start from nothing
  git add .               # index what's there now
)
```

will set up the manifest to match what's already there.

Comment: Do I need to do a git clone before I do the export and git read-tree?

Comment: You need to execute this in some repository that has filesystem access to `~/apps/appname/public` and has whatever commit you're getting your content from, but you don't need a dedicated repo for this, just the separate index you're maintaining of what's in that work tree (rather than the repo's default one).

Comment: Made the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` pathname absolute so it works with `git add .`, which cd's to the worktree first.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`git write-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-write-tree) from [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30244250), make sure to use Git 2.41+.

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), "[`git write-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d47ee0a5653441ae727e22b8985c517132c42d4c/Documentation/git-write-tree.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-write-tree))</sup> learns to work better with sparse-index.

See [commit 1a65b41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a65b41b38a669f3d6e54edec38e6b8506ef6ee1) (03 Apr 2023) by [Shuqi Liang (`none`)](https://github.com/none).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d47ee0a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d47ee0a5653441ae727e22b8985c517132c42d4c), 17 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`write-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a65b41b38a669f3d6e54edec38e6b8506ef6ee1): integrate with sparse index
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Shuqi Liang</sup>

> Update '[`git write-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1a65b41b38a669f3d6e54edec38e6b8506ef6ee1/Documentation/git-write-tree.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-write-tree))</sup> to allow using the sparse-index in memory without expanding to a full one.
>
> The recursive algorithm for `update_one()` was already updated in [2de37c5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2de37c536d54a28a032491ad4ef97632ef6ab836) ("`cache-tree`: integrate with sparse directory entries", 2021-03-03, Git v2.32.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/59bb0aa93e6edaca44b2a5488fc915d468bae46f) listed in [batch #13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e391989789db82983665667013a46eabc6fc570)) to handle sparse directory entries in the index.
> Hence we can just set the requires-full-index to false for "write-tree".
>
> The `p2000` tests demonstrate a ~96% execution time reduction for '`git write-tree`' using a sparse index:
>
> ```
> Test                                           before  after 
> -----------------------------------------------------------------
> 2000.78: git write-tree (full-v3)              0.34    0.33 -2.9% 
> 2000.79: git write-tree (full-v4)              0.32    0.30 -6.3% 
> 2000.80: git write-tree (sparse-v3)            0.47    0.02 -95.8% 
> 2000.81: git write-tree (sparse-v4)            0.45    0.02 -95.6%
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You can't clone a sub-directory. However you can create shallow clones. Such shallow clones are suitable only for deployment.

Meaning you can't Commit, Pull, Push and rebase using those clones. Shallow clones help you to reduce clone size foot print